# PowerApps aggregation connection like Visio

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-formula, powerapps-canvas

Im creating a Powerapps application to show a line connector between one object to another.

The arrow which i want to make it as adjustable and draggable. Can somebody give reference to achieve the same on that ?

Rerefernce URL [Slidercontrol based connection](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D_Kb7AXSE0s&t=477s)

Reference image mentioned below

[image: the arrow which i want to make it adjustable.]